# Nested FUSE filesystem in Python

Tags: python, filesystems, fuse

I have two different fuse filesystems in Python (subclassing `Operations`) that I combine into a single mountpoint. Right now I am creating two folders inside another and mounting them there. Something like this:

```
/mnt/myfolder/fuse1 
/mnt/myfolder/fuse2
```

(my folder is a *real* folder in filesystem)

But I would like to extend this idea to more and in a dynamical way. In other words I would like that `myfolder` is also a fuse filesystem in Python that dispatch to different objects. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @Heisenberg I have different filesystems with different capabilities (e.g. a readonly one, another that list objects based on dates, etc). And I need to compose them in a user dependent way. I have tried to dispatch commands based on the `path` argument but is a pain in the neck. I would be much easier to say mount this Operations here, that one there, and so forth.

Comment: "dispatch to different objects"  The FUSE module is already doing this for you so I dont see why you would want to reimplement it yourself.